# How to check whether pdf file exists?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pdf

I am trying to check if pdf file exists in arXiv. There are two example

> [arxiv.org/pdf/1207.4102.pdf](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.41021.pdf)
>
> [arxiv.org/pdf/1207.41021.pdf](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.41021.pdf)

The first is a pdf file and the second is not and returns an [error page](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.41021.pdf).

Is there a way to check whether a url is pdf or not. I tried the answers in [How do I check if file exists in jQuery or JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-javascript) however none of them work and they return true (i.e. file exists) for both urls. Is there a way to find which url is pdf file in JavaScript/jQuery or even PHP?

Can this be solved using [pdf.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdf.js)?

Comment: It looks like http://arxiv.org/ .htaccess is rewriting all requests and has not an error page set so... all requests will receive a 200 answer...

try http://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.41102.pdf in your browser...

You could then parse the response to see if it's html... if not then it could be your pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It return correct result.

```
function getHTTPCode($url) {

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)');
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $httpcode;
```

}

```
$url = 'http://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.41021.pdf';
if(getHTTPCode($url)==200) {
 echo  'found';
} else {
 echo  'not found';
}
```

Comment: What's the main different between your answer and mine ? Not cool to copy my answer.

Comment: It seems same except browser agent. I did not post my answer if I knew there was already curl solution. You have posted your answer while I was testing my one.

Comment: You should've checked before posting.

Comment: @PedroLobito, I don't think your answer works because it returns false for both urls.

Comment: It should, both pdfs have a 403 status code.

Comment: nope, it returns 404 which is correct. You can check both url in browser and check response code.  But your code always return 403 which is wrong

Comment: @Samir, thats right. Does this code work for any pdf or just the ones on the arXiv.

Comment: Any http request actually :)

Comment: You've copied my answer and now you're telling me it doesn't work ? look, learn to code and don't be a faker.

Comment: @PedroLobito, your code returns false for both urls when it should return true for the first.

Comment: @PedroLobito ha ha. You are the genius in the planet who can only write curl using php

Answer (score 0):

> You Can try this code for checking remote server file exists or not by Url

```
 $filename= 'arxiv.org/pdf/1207.4102.pdf';
    $file_headers = @get_headers($filename);

    if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found'){
          echo "The file $filename does not exist";
    } else if ($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.0 302 Found' && $file_headers[7] == 'HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found'){
        echo "The file $filename does not exist, and I got redirected to a custom 404 page..";
    } else {
        echo "The file $filename exists";
    }
```

Comment: @user3741635 remote server file checking, I recommend you do on server side always.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and check for a `200` [http status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) , i.e.:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.41021.pdf';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);    // we want headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);    // we don't need body
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1); // we follow redirections
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);


if($httpcode == "200"){
    echo "file exist";
}else{
    echo "doesn't exist";
}
```

---

Both pdf files return `403 Forbidden`

> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
>   Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If
>   the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public
>   why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason
>   for the refusal in the entity. If the server does not wish to make
>   this information available to the client, the status code 404 (Not
>   Found) can be used instead.

Answer (score -2):

Using PHP you can check if the file exists with http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

For remote file, check the header on a request https://stackoverflow.com/a/8139136/3222087